# State value from one React class used in another React class

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a React tabbing component and would like to export two React components from one file, one for the header tabs labels and one for the tabs panel

Here's my file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class TabsLabel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeTab: undefined,};
  }
  onTabClick(event) {
    this.setState({activeTab: this.props.labelNumber})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <s-tab onClick={this.onTabClick.bind(this)} id={"tab-" + this.props.labelNumber} aria-controls="A content">{this.props.children}</s-tab>
    );
  }
}

export class TabsPanel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.panelNumber === "1" ? (
          <div id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="A content" tabindex="0">{this.props.children}</div>
        ) : (
          <div id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="A content" tabindex="0" hidden>{this.props.children}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default (TabsLabel, TabsPanel);
```

On the page I'm using these components as so

```
      <TabsLabel labelNumber="1">Label 1</TabsLabel>
      <TabsLabel labelNumber="2">Label 2</TabsLabel>

    <TabsPanel panelNumber="1">
      <p>Panel content 1</p>
    </TabsPanel>
    <TabsPanel panelNumber="2">
      <p>Panel content 2</p>
    </TabsPanel>
```

When clicking on the TabsLabel it calls the click handler which sets the state of activeTab

What I would like to do is use this state value in the TabsPanel class but I'm not sure if that's possible or an anti pattern approach I'm doing here

In the TabsPanel class I'd like to replace the hard coded 1 string value, this

```
{this.props.panelNumber === "1"
```

With something like (with the state value from the TabsLabel class)

```
{this.props.panelNumber === this.state.activeTab
```

Comment: You can pass the same labelNumber to your TabsPanel as well. Anyways your are using the labelNumber to set the activeTab. <TabsPanel  labelNumber="1" panelNumber="1">

Comment: @d-saurabh I don't think that would work - changing {this.props.panelNumber === this.propbs.labelName would then always show all the panels as active - I need to know which label has been pressed to display the correct panel

Comment: Oh i missed that. You want to use the state of one class to another which is not directly possible. so basically you want to pass data between sibling.one way is using context api . other is using parent  class.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use context api you can do something simple like this:

```
 <TabsLabel labelNumber="1" activeTab = {(val)=>this.setState({activeTab:val})}>Label 1</TabsLabel>
 <TabsLabel labelNumber="2">Label 2</TabsLabel>

 <TabsPanel panelNumber="1" activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
      <p>Panel content 1</p>
 </TabsPanel>
 <TabsPanel panelNumber="2">
      <p>Panel content 2</p>
 </TabsPanel>
```

and in your file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class TabsLabel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {activeTab: undefined,};
  }
  onTabClick(event) {
    this.setState({activeTab: this.props.labelNumber});
    this.props.activeTab(this.props.labelNumber);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <s-tab onClick={this.onTabClick.bind(this)} id={"tab-" + this.props.labelNumber} aria-controls="A content">{this.props.children}</s-tab>
    );
  }
}

export class TabsPanel extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.panelNumber === this.props.activeTab ? (
          <div id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="A content" tabindex="0">{this.props.children}</div>
        ) : (
          <div id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="A content" tabindex="0" hidden>{this.props.children}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default (TabsLabel, TabsPanel);
```

Also you can try to keep the activeTab as state in your parent since its gonna use with multiple components.